# jQuery toggle() not working correctly

Tags: jquery, toggle

```
var main = function() {
$('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').toggle(
        function(){
            $('.menu').animate({left: "0px"});
            $('.jumbotron').animate({left: "285px"});
        },
        function(){
            $('.menu').animate({left: "-285px"});
            $('.jumbotron').animate({left: "0px"});
        }
    );
});
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Plz help sempai. My slider bar isn't working. Why tho?

The icon menu is the button and the other parts are the background and menu on a slider menu. When I click the button nothing happens and I was inquiring as to what is going on.

Comment: can you show html as well?

Comment: Do you want that to happen on load or click?

Comment: you are using wrong syntax for toggle()!

Comment: There is no `toggle` click method for new jquery versions - it was removed in [1.9](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)